# how to change terminal back to default

Tags: terminal, python

Recently I tried to set up a path for my python I ended up messing up my zsh shell. whenever I open it, this is what I see

```
Last login: Mon Nov 15 16:18:26 on ttys001

WARNING: Python 2.7 is not recommended. 
This version is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software. 
Future versions of macOS will not include Python 2.7. 
Instead, it is recommended that you transition to using 'python3' from within Terminal.

Python 2.7.18 (default, Oct  2 2021, 04:20:39) 
[GCC Apple LLVM 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.1) [+internal-os, ptrauth-isa=deploymen on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: What is in your zsh startup files? How exactly do you call python?

Comment: you mean zshrc?

Comment: Yes and others e.g. .zshenv .zloogin .zprofile